# How can I add a unique ID to each object in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

I have this array of objects and I am trying to add a unique id to each object to have the desired output as shown below .But since I am new to Javascript this is a bit hard for me please can someone help me .

This is my Array Object Input:

```
const list =  [

     {"value": "Tape Measure"},
     
     {"value": "Lawn Mower"}
  ],
```

]

This is my desired output with unique id's:

```
const desiredOuput = [
  {
    "id": "ur95tnnt949003",
    "value": "Tape Measure",
  },
  {
    "id": "0698080805kg",
    "value": "Lawn Mower",
  },

]
```

Comment: What is the logic behind those IDs? How can they be generated? What code have you tried already?

Comment: @str I just randomly typed them to illustrate the desired output but I used `Date.now()` and it's not unique so I really need your help to add unique id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample method to generate `randId`.
In the method, 1) considering mix of numbers (0-9) and lower case alphabets (a-z). 2) required length of randId (size param)

```js
const randId = (size) => {
  const nums = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) =>
    String.fromCharCode("0".charCodeAt(0) + i)
  );
  const alphabets = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) =>
    String.fromCharCode("a".charCodeAt(0) + i)
  );
  const chars = [...nums, ...alphabets];
  const rand = (length) => Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  return Array.from({ length: size }, () => chars[rand(chars.length)]).join("");
};

const list = [{ value: "Tape Measure" }, { value: "Lawn Mower" }];

const newlist = list.map(({ value }) => ({ value, id: randId(6) }));

console.log(newlist);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const list = [{
  "data": [{
      "value": "Tape Measure"
    },

    {
      "value": "Lawn Mower"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Garden Todo",
}]


const res = list.map(o => {
  o.data = o.data.map(d => ({ ...d,
    id: randomId()
  }));

  return o;
})

console.log(res)

// Change this as desired
function randomId() {
  return Math.random()
}
```

Comment: Can always `forEach` and manipulate the objects directly if it's okay to touch them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .This isn't outputting does it work?

Comment: @DilhanBhagat, yes. Just added console output.

Comment: `Math.random` is not necessarily unique. I'd probably use the index or a counter instead.

Comment: @tadman, actually `o.data` is modified. I'd rather return a new object.

Comment: @str, something like [`nanoid`](http://npmjs.com/package/nanoid) is way better

Comment: That depends. Adding a dependency if the only requirement is to have unique IDs might not be the best approach.

Comment: @str I agree maybe we can modify `Date.now` some how so we can have something unique ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
const list = [{
  "data": [{
      "value": "Tape Measure"
    },

    {
      "value": "Lawn Mower"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Garden Todo",
}]

const result = list.map(l => {
  l.data = l.data.map(d => ({id:Math.floor(Math.random() * Date.now()), ...d}));
  return l;
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

- This function will give you fully unique id

```js
function genID() {
    const timeStamp = Date.now();
    let str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    let Id = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        let rom = Math.floor(1 +(str.length -1)*Math.random());
        Id += str.charAt(rom);
    }
    Id += timeStamp.toString();
    return Id;
}
```

- You can also use only timeStamp

```js
let id = Date.now();
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install uuid`

then:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

list.forEach(el=> el.id = uuidv4());
```